# Rails Time.parse argument out of range

Tags: parsing, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, time

I'm passing a string to a `Time.parse` but seeing very interesting behavior, see excerpt from console:

```
2.1.2 :011 > Time.parse("10/10/2014 7 am")
=> 2014-10-10 07:00:00 -0700 

2.1.2 :010 > Time.parse("10/17/2014 7 am")
ArgumentError: argument out of range
```

**What's the difference???**

I'm always going to be parsing times that users input in the format of "MM/DD/YYYY H am/pm", so it's crucial that this doesn't break.

Answer (score 2):

`Time.parse` takes a format of d/m/y, and I couldn't find a way in the docs to change this to m/d/y, so instead, I just changed the input format.

Answer (score 0):

[Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem is a useful tool for this and you can set the endian_presedence to do what you want.